# every time we invoke the function it should return the old function item + the new one

Tags: javascript

Write a function addToList that accepts a string argument toDo and returns the current list as a string, every time we invoke the function it should return the old toDo item + the new one

```
    const addToList = function (toDo) {
  // TODO: Your code here
};

addToList("Eat"); // => 'Eat'
addToList("Play"); // => 'Eat Play'
addToList("Sleep"); // => 'Eat Play Sleep'
addToList("repeat"); // => 'Eat Play Sleep repeat'
```

Comment: Please refrain from adding a problem without your approach or attempt so far. It seems like a simple copy-paste which defeats the whole purpose of StackOverflow.

Comment: Got it, this is my first question here and I didn't know that ...
will do in my next questions , thx!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It looks like a homework but if you want to do that, you can create a temporary variable like this:

```js
var temp = '';

const addToList = function (toDo) {
  temp += ' ' + toDo;
  
  temp = temp.trim();
  
  console.log(temp);
};

addToList("Eat"); // => 'Eat'
addToList("Play"); // => 'Eat Play'
addToList("Sleep"); // => 'Eat Play Sleep'
addToList("repeat"); // => 'Eat Play Sleep repeat'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a closure where the outer function will declare an array and the innerFunction will take care of accruing the values.

Perform join operations to convert the array into a string each time upon inner function call.

```js
const addToListWrap = function(toDo) {
  const arr = [];
  return function(toDo) {
    arr.push(toDo);
    return arr.join(' ');
  }
};
const addToList = addToListWrap();

addToList("Eat"); // => 'Eat'
addToList("Play"); // => 'Eat Play'
addToList("Sleep"); // => 'Eat Play Sleep'
console.log(addToList("repeat")) // => 'Eat Play Sleep repeat'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like this

```
    var ToDoList = {
    toDoList:[],
    addToList: function(toDo){
    ToDoList.toDoList.push(toDo);
    return ToDoList.toDoList;
    }
}
```

And Add Elements to it like this

```
ToDoList.addToList("Play")
```